# Jetty JVM is freezing

Tags: java, jetty

I have 2 Jetty servers with the same problem,
The Jetty web app gets "freeze" every couple of hours.
(Freeze means that the console is not doing anything/unable to receive new requests)

During the "Freeze" I noticed that the JVM is using more swap than it usually does.
It seems like sort of a memory leak, even tough the system has enough memory.

I run the JVM with those run parameters:
-Xms8000m -Xmx280000m

Those are the RAM graphs (blank lines are what I called "freeze"):
See reference number 1 below

I also noticed the the garbage collector is not running very frequent.
Maybe it is related?
See reference number 2 below

I'd appreciate any input regarding a proper use of the garbage collector and any other ideas that would help resolve it

- This is a spring/Hibernate based Application.

  1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGOkM.jpg
  2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI1mt.jpg

Comment: Looks like you have intermediate full garbage collections. This can take a while with such big heaps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it does make scene, what do you think is the best practice for the memory heaps? maybe -Xms28000m -Xmx28000m?

Comment: You need to find out what it is that is filling the heap - a profiler will help you with that.

Comment: How much physical and swap memory does that system have? How much memory are other processes using during the white lines?

Comment: @ninjalj The system has 32GB RAM and a SWAP partition of 4GB. During those white lines the system cpu is at load avg. of 2

Comment: Also the system has 4GB free during the freezes, there are no other processes on the server that takes significant amount of resources

Comment: this question is more appropriate for ServerFault